# SQL recursion query assistance

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I have a table in a SQL DB that stores the User, Computer and Date every time an individual logs in to a machine. I need a way of determining what computers are logged in to by a specific person (date is irrelevant), but also a list of all the other people who also logged in to those computers...and any computers they have logged on to...and all the users who logged on to THOSE computers...and so on.

For example, 
Bob logs on to computers A, B and C. 
John also logs on to B and C but also D. 
Frank logs on to D. 
Jim logs on to D, E, F. 
Andrew logs on to A and F.

I would want to show ALL of these relationships. Doesn't have to be in this format, but:

- Bob -> A -> Andrew
- Bob -> B -> John -> D -> Frank
- Bob -> C -> John -> D -> Frank
- Bob -> B -> John -> D -> Jim -> E
- Bob -> C -> John -> D -> Jim -> E
- Bob -> B -> John -> D -> Jim -> F -> Andrew
- Bob -> C -> John -> D -> Jim -> F -> Andrew

I know it's got to use at least one recursive query, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: the ordering is dependent to log-in time ?

Comment: Sounds like this would be better done in a mapping software like IBM Analyst Notebook or Visallo or something since the recursion could be infinite.

Comment: @scsimon if the table is finite, the recursion should be finite in respect

Comment: @Idle001  I wasn't being literal with the definition of infinite, since of course it will end, but at what cost? If the depth is 200K... 3million? At what point would this be synonymous with infinite for a SQL Engine where looping is slow, and recursion is next in line. I don't understand what *if the table is finite* really means. Of course, all tables are finite.

Comment: and this would make the outcome in exponential volume, i agree no matter how much you set max_recursion option, there is a dead end when sql manager would overflow

Comment: Log in time doesn't matter. Regarding the infinite recursion, that's not going to happen. It's not like it's thousands of machines shared by thousands of users. For instance, only half of the users user more than one computer and of the ones that do, only a few use more than 2 or 3. Also, the users are spread across sites, and they only share machines within their individual site.

Comment: @jmon then can you post some sample data? It all depends on what the schema looks like.

Comment: User: Computer: Date:
User2 ComputerA 07/24/2017
User1 ComputerA 08/02/2017
User1 ComputerB 07/31/2017
User3 ComputerB 07/21/2017
User1 ComputerC 08/22/2017
User3 ComputerC 07/31/2017
User1 ComputerC 07/25/2017
User3 ComputerC 08/16/2017
User4 ComputerC 07/25/2017
User1 ComputerD 08/14/2017
User4 ComputerD 08/22/2017
User5 ComputerE 08/11/2017
User6 ComputerE 08/04/2017
User1 ComputerE 08/02/2017
User7 ComputerE 07/21/2017
User1 ComputerF 08/01/2017
User8 ComputerF 08/18/2017
User9 ComputerF 08/11/2017
User1 ComputerG 07/25/2017
User9 ComputerH 07/21/2017

Comment: @jmon there must be some itinerary for recursive calls to walk through if it is not time, unless you want it to be endless recursion

Comment: It can use the time for recursion purposes, but from the data that I need to report on, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> ### **Edit**:
>
> - The query supports two ways starting from both shared computers, and sharing users
> - Removing duplicates from terminal chains

It looks like this is possible after a long half-day battling my head with progressive queries.

Using CTE recurrent statements of course, I could list along all the chaining events occured following a time line with some eventual exceptions, the most blatant is recursivity toleration of the server that blows off, just with 50 records i should wait for a remarkable period.

Assuming that the table exists already with the figuring columns : `person,computer,at`

```
WITH
recurrent_table as (
       select 0 step , t.person perstart , t.computer compstart , t.at timestart , cast('' as nvarchar) chain , convert (varchar(1) , '') perswait2chain , convert (varchar(1) , '') compwait2chain , t.person persend , t.computer compend , t.at timend
       from @logs t 
    union all
       select 1 step , t.person perstart , t.computer compstart , t.at timestart , cast ('' as nvarchar) chain , convert (varchar(1) , '') perswait2chain , convert (varchar(1) , '') compwait2chain , t.person persend , t.computer compend , t.at timend
       from @logs t 
    union all
       select step+1 step , r.perstart perstart , r.compstart compstart , r.timestart timestart , convert (nvarchar , r.chain + r.perswait2chain + r.compwait2chain)  chain , convert (varchar(1) , t.person) perswait2chain , convert (varchar(1) , t.computer) compwait2chain , t.person persend , t.computer compend , t.at timend
       from @logs t , recurrent_table r 
    where (
       ( r.persend = t.person and step%2 = 1 ) 
    or
       ( r.compend = t.computer and step%2 = 0 )
    ) and t.at > r.timend
)
```

This recursive call is a thorough sweeper that compiles all possible junctions, the worst way to deal in sql than any other DB miner, with a case-switch at every alternating `step` to tell where to compare a common used computer, or a transferring user, the abundant parameters in the recursive table are to be used for filtering purpose, like when user `A` use machine `1` than machine `1` will be used by `B` then `B` use `2`, only the longest chain `A1B1B2` should count.

```
select distinct timestart 'started at' , timend 'ended at' , ct.perstart + ct.compstart + ct.chain + ct.perswait2chain + ct.compwait2chain 'chain of events' 
from recurrent_table ct
where not exists (
     select chain from recurrent_table rc where
        cast (ct.perstart + ct.compstart + ct.chain + ct.persend + ct.compend as nvarchar) = cast (rc.chain + rc.persend + rc.compend as nvarchar) 
     or cast (ct.perstart + ct.compstart + ct.chain + ct.perswait2chain + ct.compwait2chain as nvarchar) = cast (rc.chain + rc.perswait2chain + rc.compwait2chain as nvarchar) 
     or cast (ct.perstart + ct.compstart + ct.chain + ct.persend + ct.compend as nvarchar) = cast (rc.perstart + rc.compstart + rc.chain as nvarchar) 
     or ( rc.perswait2chain != '' 
          and cast (ct.perstart + ct.compstart + ct.chain + ct.perswait2chain + ct.compwait2chain as nvarchar) = cast (rc.perstart + rc.compstart + rc.chain as nvarchar) 
     )
)
order by timestart , timend
option ( MAXRECURSION  32767 )
```

this far, it would be noticable that the conditional filter sided with a sorting order is able to make you feel the keyboard melting between your hands from the heat emitted by your chipset, it's really wise to use a graph generator or an intelligent information digger for larger records. Or should it exist some shorter breakthough that works with implicit calls, both hands sql isn't really your man.

there is another exception where two chains of these forms come togather ...

A1 C1 C2 H2 H4 T4 T1 from 1:00 to 15:00

and

A1 T1 from 1:00 to 15:00

Those symbolic chains are caught within same time difference, where the last one surely implies alot of hidden events folded within it, that's because the query interpreter isn't selective, even selecting the closest timestamp would exclude alot of valid options, making a choice of the longest sequence between same timestamps also is exclusive of some rare eventualities like:

A1 C1 C2 H2 H4 T4 T1 from 1:00 to 15:00

A1 B1 B2 I2 I4 T4 T1 from 1:00 to 15:00

Only if my logic isn't flawed or vulnerable to an invalidating counter-example, either of these configurations are safe, the only walkthrough is making things more complicate by devoting an everlasting sub-sequence finder to match similarities and extract useless ones.

That's the overall:

```
declare @users table(psn char)
declare @computers table(comp char)

declare @logs table(person varchar(1), computer varchar(1), at DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATETIME())

declare @cnt int
set @cnt=1

WHILE @cnt < 50
BEGIN
   insert @logs(person,computer) values (char(cast(DATEPART(nanosecond,SYSDATETIME())/1050 as int)%10+97), cast( DATEDIFF(nanosecond,cast(GETDATE () as datetime2),SYSDATETIME())/90 as int)%10+1)
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.035';
END;

select person , computer as 'used computer ' , at from  @logs;

WITH
recurrent_table as (
select 0 step, t.person perstart, t.computer compstart,t.at timestart, cast('' as nvarchar) chain , convert(varchar(1),'') perswait2chain , convert(varchar(1),'') compwait2chain, t.person persend , t.computer compend, t.at timend
from @logs t 
union all
select 1 step, t.person perstart, t.computer compstart,t.at timestart, cast('' as nvarchar) chain , convert(varchar(1),'') perswait2chain , convert(varchar(1),'') compwait2chain, t.person persend , t.computer compend, t.at timend
from @logs t 
union all
select step+1 step , r.perstart perstart, r.compstart compstart,r.timestart timestart, convert(nvarchar,r.chain + r.perswait2chain + r.compwait2chain )  chain , convert(varchar(1),t.person) perswait2chain ,convert(varchar(1),t.computer) compwait2chain , t.person persend , t.computer compend, t.at timend
from @logs t 
, recurrent_table r 
where (
       ( r.persend = t.person  and step%2 = 1 ) or
       ( r.compend = t.computer and step%2 = 0 )
      ) and t.at > r.timend
)
select distinct timestart 'started at' , timend 'ended at', ct.perstart + ct.compstart + ct.chain + ct.perswait2chain + ct.compwait2chain 'chain of events' 
from recurrent_table ct
where not exists ( select chain  from recurrent_table rc 
where cast (ct.perstart+ct.compstart+ct.chain+ct.persend+ct.compend as nvarchar) = cast (rc.chain+rc.persend+rc.compend as nvarchar) 
or
cast (ct.perstart+ct.compstart+ct.chain+ct.perswait2chain+ct.compwait2chain as nvarchar) = cast (rc.chain+rc.perswait2chain+rc.compwait2chain as nvarchar) 
or
cast (ct.perstart+ct.compstart+ct.chain+ct.persend+ct.compend as nvarchar) = cast (rc.perstart+rc.compstart+rc.chain as nvarchar) 
or
( rc.perswait2chain != '' and cast (ct.perstart+ct.compstart+ct.chain+ct.perswait2chain+ct.compwait2chain as nvarchar) = cast (rc.perstart+rc.compstart+rc.chain as nvarchar) )
)
order by ct.timestart,ct.timend
option ( MAXRECURSION  32767)
;
```

Just pay attention the first timestamps used for seeding my random generator, differently that the one used for tagging user-machine occurences.